# generating rtf from template in c# winforms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a simple process someone can recommend for generating an rtf document from a pre-built "template" and populate fields.

I would prefer to avoid ms word automation type solutions as i cannot guarantee ms office versions etc.

Resulting file needs to be editable so I cant go pdf

is it as simple as using something like nvelocity, or do i need to do something fancier?
thanks

Comment: You should check it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter, Might be, It can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use keywords : Example:

This is a [text] that needs to be [replaced]

and the use a stringbuilder to replace the keywords.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(yourTemplate);
sb.Replace("[text]", "car");
sb.Replace("[replaced]", "washed");
```

So if you get me the final text will be :

This is a car that needs to be wahsed.

This is just one way of doing it.